# Primefaces inputtextarea's autocomplete issue

Tags: primefaces

I want to close autocomplete component of inputtextarea by clicking anywhere in the inputtextarea.
Now it is working with 'Esc' button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<p:inputTextarea ... onclick="pressClick();" onkeydown="presskey();"/>
```

```js
              function pressClick() {
              alert("testClick");
              var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-autocomplete-panel");
      for(var i = 0; i &lt; divsToHide.length; i++)
                 {
                  divsToHide[i].style.visibility="hidden";
                 }
             }
             function presskey() {
              var divsToShow = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-autocomplete-panel");

              for(var i = 0; i &lt; divsToShow.length; i++)
              {
               divsToShow[i].style.visibility="hidden";
              }

             }
```